# Call a function from a html added with html() function

Tags: javascript, html, function, append

I have this function into a javascript file :

```
function toggle_concessions(concessions) {

    var text =  
            "<table>"+
            "<tr><td class='concession-name'>gfhgfbfghfd</td><td class='op-encours'>| 15 opérations en cours</td></tr>"+
            "<tr class='stats'><td class='concession-adresse'>ghfhdfhdgh</td><td class='voir-concessions'><img id='11' src='img/voirlesoperations.jpg' onclick='toggle_operations('ffff');'></td></tr>"+
            "</table>";
            ;

    if($("#"+concessions).attr("class")!="concessions toggled"){
        $("#"+concessions).html(text);
        $("#"+concessions).toggleClass("toggled");          

    }else{
        $("#"+concessions).toggleClass("");
    }

    $("#"+concessions).toggle("slow");
}
```

The function "toggle_operations()" isn't working when I click on the image. Even when I execute an alert it doesn't work.

What can I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your html-embedded js is not well formed due to wrong pairing of string delimiters - you have to escape the quotes surrounding the argument to you `toggle_operations` call:

```
"<tr class='stats'><td class='concession-adresse'>ghfhdfhdgh</td><td class='voir-concessions'><img id='11' src='img/voirlesoperations.jpg' onclick='toggle_operations(\'ffff\');'></td></tr>"+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still have he same problem, it says

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: @HappyLearner: what does your `toggle_operations` function look like ?

Comment: Finaly I've got it, I just put : onclick='toggle_operations();' with no argument. The problem is that it doesn't find the function. The alert() is working. The function toggle_operations() is in the same javascript file.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: operations is not defined

Comment: without actually inspecting all of your code (in particular the js file or `<script>` section containing `toggle_operations` it's essentially impossible to provide further help.